# I forgot my password Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: password-recovery

I travelled from South America and I installed my old HDD and I forgot my Sudo Password.  Please help me in retrieving it.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot into the recovery option (in grub). You may have to hold shift while booting to see grub. Then, at the shell run the command:

```
passwd yourusernamehere
```

Enter a new password and reboot.

Comment: That ask me to login first

Comment: so need old ID and pass

Answer (score 0):

Boot up using a Live CD like DSL or Slax. Then open `etc/shadow` **of Ubuntu partition (which you've forgot it's root password)** where you see something like below:

> root:$1$aB7mx0Licb$CTbs2RQrfPHkz5Vna0.fnz8H68tB.:10852:0:99999:7:::

Just remove the string betwwen first `:` and second one i.e. you should have

> root::10852:0:99999:7:::

Save the file and you'll be able to login to `root` without any password. And `root` can change your other user's passwords.

If you have already another host like Windows, you can use for example `ext2fsd` to open the file in Windows rather than a Live CD.